# Designing a data-driven logic system

Tags: c#, sql, design-patterns, database-design

I'm developing a tax calculation system that applies various taxes based on a set of supplied criteria.
The information frequently changes, so I'm trying to create a way to store all these logic rules in the database.

As you can imagine, there is a lot of compound logic involved in applying taxes.
For example, a tax might only apply *if A is true, B is less than 100, and C equals 7*.

My current design is terrible.
I have a few database columns for very common criteria filtering, such as location and tax year.
For more complex logic, I have a column that holds JavaScript, and in code, I run an interpreter to filter the results.  Performance and maintainability suck.

I'd like to improve this design by making the logic entirely data-driven, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly represent this logic within a relational database.  What is a good way to model this logic in the database?

Comment: it's not really clear where you have a difficulties. Is it about a performance of *managing* data?

Comment: This kind of logic is best expressed in code. That doesn't mean the code can't be dynamic (i.e. a script) and stored in the database.  But I just feel you could end up with a bit of an ugly solution here. When you parse an expression you end up with a tree data structure, not a list, so if you do want to go down this route think trees.

Comment: @Tigran I updated my question: "What is a good way to represent this logic within a relational database?"  I eventually plan on creating a UI to manage it, but that's a lower priority.

Comment: you can build a dynamic sql using these conditions you've specified in this table then build your corresponding to each tax I assume. Why return 1000 records where you retrieve conditions for 1 tax and build your dynamic sql for it then execute it and proceed?

Comment: @JamesGaunt You are correct, a tree data structure is definitely more appropriate.  I removed my table idea from my question.  If you have any ideas on a tree design, I'm listening!

Comment: @JamesGaunt I'm concerned with using scripts, because there's no way to filter them in the DB, so I have to evaluate all scripts in code.

Comment: I'm struggling because I don't really understand the objectives. Do you want non-technical users to be able to edit these expressions? Is ease of editing or speed of evaluating more important? Why do you need to filter expressions - what do you need to filter them on? How complex do these expressions need to be?

Comment: +1. I maintained a factory management system that stores complex business rules as bits and pieces of sql code like `WHERE` and `JOIN ... ON ...`. Interested to know how to do it in the right way.

Comment: A relevant collection of articles from Alex's Soapbox at DailyWTF: [Soft Coding](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Soft_Coding.aspx); [The Mythical Business Layer](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Mythical-Business-Layer.aspx); [Programming Sucks](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Programming-Sucks!-Or-At-Least,-It-Ought-To-.aspx), and what you risk creating: [The Enterprise Rules Engine](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Enterprise_Rules_Engine.aspx). I'm not saying these are 100% gospel truth, but they are geniunely thought-provoking.

Comment: Also google 'Turing tarpit'. And good luck :)

Comment: @AakashM Great articles ... I loved this nugget: "The only way to insulate your software from business rule changes is to build a completely generic program that’s devoid of all business rules yet can implement any rule. Oh, and they’ve already built that tool. It’s called C++. And Java. And C#. And Basic. And, dare I say, COBOL. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on this similar issue for over a year now for a manufacturing cost generation application. Similarly, it takes in loads of product design data input and base on the design, and other inventory considerations such as quantity, bulk purchase options, part supplier, electrical ratings etc. The result is a list of direct materials, labour and costs.

I knew from the onset that what I need is some kind of query language instead of a computational one, and it has to be scripted, not compiled. But I have yet to find a perfect solution:

**METHOD 1 - SQL**
I created tables that represents my objects and columns that represents properties and then manually typed in the all the SQL SELECT statments required in an item_rules table. What I did was to first save the object into the database, then then I did

```
rules = SELECT * FROM item_rules
foreach(rules as _rule)
{
   count = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (_rule[select_statement]) as T1
   if(count > 1) itemlist.add(_rule[item_that_satisfy_rule])
}
```

What it does is it takes each rule in the item_rules table and run it against my object that is now in the tables. e.g. SELECT * FROM my_object WHERE A=5 AND B>10. If I successfully pick it up, I get a positive count and then I know I should include the corresponding rule item to my items list.

**METHOD 2 - NCALC**
Instead of storing the queries in SQL format, I found the NCALC opensource expression parsing library. NCALC takes a string expression and option variable and computes a result. The string expressions can be stored in plain text on the filesystem.

**METHOD 3 - EXCEL**
EXCEL is actually a very good piece of software for doing data lookups. You can create the formulas in excel and then feed data from your application into excel and then let excel run the formulas to give you the results. Advantage is that many people knows how to use excel, so different people can maintain it.

But like I say, none of these are perfect for me. I am just sharing and hopefully we can get better recommedations.

Comment: NCalc looks really cool -- I was considering implementing something like it, so now I don't have to :)  I'm going to ponder these 3 methods, and I'll let you know what I think!  Thanks.

Comment: What language is your code example?  Pseudo-code?  Some SQL variant?

Comment: Here's my conclusion: My current solution isn't too bad. Basically, I use table columns to filter the most common criteria, and I use the "expression" column for all the one-off scenarios.  This is a good balance between performance and flexibility.

Comment: The NCalc method, by the way, is GREAT! I compared performance to JINT, and in a simple scenario, NCalc was 17x faster!!  Thank you very much for recommending it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to go with Jake's approach, You can use Dynamic Sql too.